# Bootstrap modal related target

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm following the Bootstrap Modals documentation (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target) and trying to include a variable field within an enquiry form that appears when a button is clicked. Depending on which button is pressed I want to populate an input field with a particular value.

My JavaScript is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
        var recipient = button.data('whatever') 
        var modal = $(this)
        modal.find('.modal-title').text('Enquiry regarding ' + recipient)
        modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
    })

</script>
```

This line:

```
modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
```

targets all the input fields in my form, but I want it to target just a single input by ID

Can anyone advise?

Regards,

Neal

Answer (score 3):

Give your input field an ID, e.g.

```
<input id="someid">
```

Target that input's ID in your js code, e.g.

```
modal.find('#someid').val(recipient)
```

Comment: @NealFoster No worries, glad to help.